# Dealing with Login Map in Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS login example, but I'm having a problem.

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/CognitoSyncDemo

Once I log in,  I save the (Developer Authenticatiion) login credentials using the setLogins method.

/**
     * Sets the login so that you can use authorized identity. This requires a
     * network request, so you should call it in a background thread.
     * 
     * @param providerName the name of the external identity provider
     * @param token openId token
     */
    public static void addLogins(String providerName, String token) {
        if (syncClient == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("CognitoSyncClientManager not initialized yet");
        }

```
    Map<String, String> logins = credentialsProvider.getLogins();
    if (logins == null) {
        logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }
    logins.put(providerName, token);
    credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);
}
```

However, this information is not persisted into the example. Thus, If I close and open my app application, the credentialsProvider.getLogins() will be empty.

The AWS example is not persisting the login map. There is something wrong with it? Without any information on the login map, I got a error

com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.NotAuthorizedException: Unauthenticated access

Answer (score 1):

Currently the above sample does not cover the part of managing and refreshing the tokens from external IdPs (Eg: Facebook, google, twitter etc) but shows the examples of how to obtain the first token from the IdP, and to use Cognito once a valid token is populated in the logins map. Values in the logins map are typically the short lived token vended by the external IdP and needs to be updated if expired. Typically the IdPs provide a long lived refresh token which can be cached and can be used to get the short lived token, but this logic is specific to the type of IdP.